# Server that records live streams?

Tags: linux, record, flash-media-server, live-streaming

Does anybody know of a server that can record live streams published by a FMS?

Comment: What's an [FMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FMS) in your world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at HelixServer
http://www.realnetworks.com/products-services/helix-server-proxy.aspx